# Problemas con vistas en python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente problema y resulta que estoy haciendo una pequeña interfaz de usuario para un proyecto de la universidad y me esta presentando el siguiente error y es cuando ejecuto un botón para abrir otra ventana, la información que debería mostrarse en la segunda pantalla se muestra en la primera pero aún así se ejecuta la pantalla en blanco no se como solucionar el problema se lo agradecería a la persona que me pueda ayudar.

Aquí el código que tengo por ahora

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def pantalla_principal():
    global pantallaPrincipal
    pantallaPrincipal = Tk()
    pantallaPrincipal.geometry("560x450")
    pantallaPrincipal.title("Bienvenido")
    pantallaPrincipal.iconbitmap("resource\logo.ico")
    
    label = Label(pantallaPrincipal, text="Apps", fg="black", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Ingrese a Login", height="3", width="30", command=menu_pantalla).pack()
    pantallaPrincipal.mainloop()

def menu_pantalla():
    global pantallaPoliedro
    pantallaPoliedro = Tk()
    pantallaPoliedro.geometry("300x380")
    pantallaPoliedro.title("Bienvenidos a Login")
    pantallaPoliedro.iconbitmap("resource\logo.ico")
    
    Label(text="Acceso al Sistema", bg="LightCoral", fg="white", width="300", height="3", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Iniciar Sesión", height="3", width="30").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Registrar", height="3", width="30").pack()


pantalla_principal()
```

Aquí la imagen de como aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Tienes que asignar el segundo `label`, `button`, etc a `menu_pantalla`: `label = Label(menu_pantalla, etc`

Comment: Disculpa no te entiendo podrías por favor enseñarme como, que pena las molestias.

Comment: En la función `pantalla_principal` has escrito: `label = Label(pantallaPrincipal, text="Apps", fg="black", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()`, pero en la función `menu_pantalla` no has escrito algo similar para su propio contenido: `label = Label(pantallaPoliedro , text="Acceso al Sistema", fg="black", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()`, por ejemplo...

Comment: No funciona pasa exactamente lo mismo solo que ahora la otra ventana aparece con un titulo

Comment: ¿Un título que pone `Acceso sistema`? Tienes que hacer algo similar con los botones, etc., cambiando los colores, tipos de letra, etc. a tu gusto...

Comment: amigo ya te entendí ya lo pude solucionar mil gracias por tu ayuda y paciencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Cuando creas widgets, el primer argumento es en que ventana o Frame lo vas a crear. Si no pasas este argumento, el widget se crea en la ventana raíz.
Lo que estás haciendo es inicializar otra ventana con Tk cuando presiona un botón en la primera ventana. [Esto no es recomendado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged). Más tarde profundizaré en como puedes hacer.

Pero la conclusión es que por alguna razón interna (la cual desconozco) Tkinter eligió la primera ventana como tu ventana raiz.

#### Soluciones

A continuación explicaré algunas soluciones a los problemas que implican el uso de Tk multiples veces y como deberías asociar los widgets a la segunda ventana.

###### Solucion 1: Destruir la ventana anterior

Lo que puedes hacer es destruir la ventana anterior y luego crear la nueva con Tk().

```
def menu_pantalla():
    pantallaPrincipal.destroy()

    global pantallaPoliedro
    pantallaPoliedro = Tk()

    ...

    Label(text="Acceso al Sistema", bg="LightCoral", fg="white", width="300", height="3", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    ...
```

En este caso particular puedes no pasar el primer argumento, ya que por default se crearán en la nueva ventana Tk(). La desventaja de esta solución es que no puedes conservar la ventana original. Vease las siguientes soluciones para conservar la ventana.

###### Solución 2: Toplevels (recomendado)

Puedes hacer que la segunda ventana sea un Toplevel, que funciona casi igual a una ventana Tk, pero tiene la ventaja de que se cierra cuando cierras la ventana padre.

```
def menu_pantalla():
    global pantallaPoliedro
    # Como no le paso ningún argumento, por default el padre del toplevel será la ventana raíz. 
    pantallaPoliedro = Toplevel()

    ...

    Label(pantallaPoliedro, text="Acceso al Sistema", bg="LightCoral", fg="white", width="300", height="3", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(pantallaPoliedro, text="").pack()

    ...
```

En este caso, hay que aclarar que quieres crear los widgets en el toplevel pasando dicho toplevel como primer argumento, como se ve en el código de arriba.

###### Solución 3: Dejalo como está (no recomendado)

Puedes dejar tu código como está, pero en tu camino te encontrarás con comportamientos inesperados como el de ahora. Requerirás hacer ciertas acciones para evitar dichos. Ni siquiera yo se del todo que acciones hay que hacer. Parece que una de las cosas a hacer sería pasar el argumento master a los StringVars, IntVars, PhotoImage, etc como dice [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69062053/12913664).

En mi opinión, esto es trabajo extra innecesario y aun así podrían ocurrir comportamientos inesperados que no se han mencionado en la respuesta enlazada.

#### Bonus: convenciones, buenas practicas y errores

En Python existen algunas convenciones y buenas practicas que están buenas seguir. Aquí dejo algunas:

###### importar tkinter

Algunos tutoriales viejos muestran como buena manera de importar tkinter el `from tkinter import *`, pero ahora no se considera buena practica. Puedes usar:

- `from tkinter import <lo que necesites>` esto funciona similar a `from tkinter import *`, pero solo importa lo que le pidas. Por ejemplo `from tkinter import Tk, Button` solo importan los objetos Tk y Button. No todo lo demás que podrías o no usar.
  Esta forma, aunque no requiere ningún cambio en tu código, es un poco pesada de usar. Pues cada vez que necesites algo más del modulo Tkinter conforme avanzas tendrás que agregarlo a la "lista" de importaciones.
- `import tkinter as tk` De este modo importamos el modulo entero con el nombre tk. Esto requerirá que hagas un cambio en el código y agregues `tk.` a cada objeto de tkinter. Como el `Label(...` sería `tk.Label(...`.
  Personalmente, recomiendo este modo, es buena practica y es más cómodo.

Otra cosa que cabe aclarar, no es necesario importar Tkinter de varias formas diferentes. Alcanza solo con una de ellas.

###### var = widget(...).pack()

Este error lo he notado más de una vez. `widget(...).pack()` devuelve None, por lo que lo que se guarda en var **no** es el widget, es el objeto None.
Para evitar esto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var = widget(...)
var.pack()
```

O si no necesitas guardar el widget en una variable:

```
widget(...).pack()
```

###### Escritura de variables

Al escribir el nombre de una variable, hay una convención que dice que es mejor escribir el nombre de las variables con minusculas y separando las palabras por guiones bajos. Por ejemplo la variable `pantallaPrincipal` sería `pantalla_principal`. Te recomiendo leer https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions