# Tkinter: "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero colocar una imagen en un boton con este codigo:

```
btn_calculator = Image.open('calculator.png')
btn_calculator = btn_calculator.resize((125, 125))
window.btn_calculator = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_calculator)
```

Pero me aparece este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\THIAGO\Programacion\Python\SweetHome\startup.py", line 173, in <module>
    start() 
  File "e:\THIAGO\Programacion\Python\SweetHome\startup.py", line 150, in start
    calculator = Button(window, image=window.btn_calculator, width=125, height=125, bd=0, bg="black", command=openCalculator)
  File "C:\Users\Thiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2679, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Thiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: De causalidad estás creando varias ventanas usando la clase Tk?

Comment: Si, la idea es una aplicacion que tenga varias aplicaciones, es como un simulador de sistema operativo, eso causa algun inconveniente?

Comment: Si, causa inconvenientes si no lo manejas correctamente. Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/513335/158880

Comment: Gracias! Le echare un vistazo

Comment: Estuve leyendo, pero el problema no es que no se abran las ventanas, el problema son los imagenes, no se porque no se cargan o que. Aplique una de esas soluciones y obtuve el mismo resultado

Comment: Es verdad, ahí me enfoco en otro problema. Pero la causa es la misma. Es raro eso... Con una de esas soluciones debería de funcionarte. Podrías publicar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ver que está pasando por favor?

Comment: De las soluciones que propuse, de la que estoy más seguro de que funcionaría es la segunda.

Comment: Lo siento pero no tengo mucho tiempo para eso, no hay alguna parte especifica que te interesaria ver del codigo?

Comment: No hay problema, pero me será más dificil ayudarte como verás. No se me ocurre que puedes mostrarme de especifico... Lo mejor que se me ocurre es que pruebes las otras soluciones a ver si te funcionan. Te pedía el ejemplo por que no se me ocurre que podría estar pasando y mirar un código con el mismo problema podría servirme para identificarlo. Si tu código es corto, podrías agregarlo a la pregunta y listo.

Comment: No es muy corto, ese es el problema jaja

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136769/discussion-between-dante-s-and-skeletoos57).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solucion

Cambie `window = Tk()` por `window = Toplevel()` y ya funciono perfectamente.