# Error al mostrar DataFrame con PandasTable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, table

Lo extraño esque al presionar el botón *Generar*, no se ve el Dataframe, pero si le doy vuelta a la rueda del mouse, aparece. Ya traté de buscar la solción pero no he encontrado algo parecido. El código que comparto es sólo el código de la ventana donde pasa este error. **Si la tabla la pongo en un tk.TopLevel() no aparece ese error.**

**Al presionar el botón:**

[image: Al]

**Al darle vuelta a la rueda del mouse:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay manera de hacer que aparezca en el momento que se presiona el botón?

```
    def generartabla():
        # tabla = tk.Toplevel()
        # tabla.iconbitmap("interfazGraficaUsuario\icono2.ico")
        # tabla.title("Inventario general")
        pt = Table(frame_tabla, dataframe=df_existencias_centros, enable_menus=True, showstatusbar=True, editable=True)
        pt.show()
        pt.focus_force()

    # *************** conexión a DB y obtención del DF **********************
    # conexicon a DB
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("gestorInventariosdb.db")
    # creación de df
    try:
        df_existencias = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM existencias", con=conexion)
        df_centrosLogisticos = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM centrosLogisticos", con=conexion)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="Ocurrió un error al cargar la base de datos.")

    # merge 
    df_existencias_centros = pd.merge(left=df_existencias, right=df_centrosLogisticos, how='left', on='Centro')
    # filtrado de columnas
    df_existencias_centros = df_existencias_centros[['Centro', 'Nombre', 'Código', 'Descripción', 'Existencias']]
    
    conexion.close()
    # **********************************************************************

    ventana = tk.Tk()
    ventana.title("Centros logisticos")
    #ventana.geometry("280x70")
    ventana.iconbitmap("interfazGraficaUsuario\icono2.ico")
    ventana.focus_force()
    #ventana.configure(padx=10, pady=10)

    frame_opciones = tk.Frame(ventana)
    frame_tabla = tk.Frame(ventana)
    
    frame_opciones.grid(sticky="n")
    frame_tabla.grid(sticky="s")

    # *********** menu bar **********************
    menubar = tk.Menu(ventana)

    archivo = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    archivo.add_command(label="Cerrar", command=ventana.destroy)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=archivo)

    ayuda = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    ayuda.add_command(label="Manual de usuario")
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=ayuda)
    # ********************************************

    # ****************** creacion de widgets **********************
    label_centro = tk.Label(frame_opciones, text='Centro')
    texto_centro = tk.Text(frame_opciones, height=1, width=30)
    boton_generar = tk.Button(frame_opciones, text='Generar', command=generartabla)

    # ***************** colocacion de widgets ********************
    label_centro.grid(row=0, column=0)
    texto_centro.grid(row=0, column=1)
    boton_generar.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
    # **************** configuraciones de widgets *************************
    texto_centro.configure(font=("arial", 10))


    ventana.config(menu=menubar)
    ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No logro reproducir el error. Estás seguro de que no lo solucionaste el error mientras preparabas el código publicado?

Comment: Hola. No, aún lo tengo. Cabe mencionar que el código publicado es sólo una parte. No sé si sea por eso que a ti no te aparece. Si gustas te paso el repositorio donde lo tengo completo:

https://github.com/0M1N1D0/Gestor-de-inventarios.git

Comment: He revisado un poco el código. Parece que tu tabla no carga correctamente debido a un error. Y es que tk.Tk debe ser llamado solo una vez (para crear la ventana principal). Que dos ventanas raices (creadas con tk.Tk) existan al mismo tiempo, suele traer problemas como este (que una imagen no se pueda cargar). A otra persona le pasó algo similar hace tiempo, por favor checkea esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/513335/158880, o esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509131/158880 y la más parecida a tu error https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527198/158880

Comment: Va, muchas gracias, ¡lo revisaré!